# ANTLR4 not parsing typedef

Tags: c, antlr, antlr4

I am using ANTLR4 and the canonical grammar for C as found here:
https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/c

I am not modifying the grammar in any way.  I am finding that the parsing is failing on `typedef` statements that occur outside of functions.  The simplest example I can give:

**PASSES:**

```
main()
{
    typedef unsigned int UINT;
    return 0;
}
```

**FAILS:**

```
typedef unsigned int UINT;

main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The error message is:

> line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'typedef'

I am not aware of any rule in C that says typedefs must appear inside functions.  Is this a bug in the ANTLR C grammar, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me:

`antlr4 C.g4
javac *.java
grun C compilationUnit -tree t.c
(compilationUnit (translationUnit (translationUnit (externalDeclaration (declaration (declarationSpecifiers (declarationSpecifier (storageClassSpecifier typedef)) (declarationSpecifier (typeSpecifier unsigned)) (declarationSpecifier (typeSpecifier int)) (declarationSpecifier (typeSpecifier (typedefName UINT)))) ;))) (externalDeclaration (functionDefinition (declarator (directDeclarator (directDeclarator main) ( ))) (compoundStatement { (blockItemList (blockItem (statement (jumpStatement return (expression (assignmentExpression (conditionalExpression (logicalOrExpression (logicalAndExpression (inclusiveOrExpression (exclusiveOrExpression (andExpression (equalityExpression (relationalExpression (shiftExpression (additiveExpression (multiplicativeExpression (castExpression (unaryExpression (postfixExpression (primaryExpression 0))))))))))))))))) ;)))) })))) <EOF>)`

ANTLR version issue? classpath diff between javac and antlr4?

Comment: Thanks ANTLR Guy, I was using primaryExpression as my start rule.  I switched to compilationUnit, and it works for me too.  Unfortunately, my actual code still isn't working, but I'll open a separate question for that if I can't make it work.